# Spark, Scala, Databricks, combine and add columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark/Scala to attempt a "simple" query. I have a file which, after line 1 below runs, looks like this

```
EmpReg,EmpOT,RegPay,OTPay
Alice,Alice,400,20
Bob,Bob,300,0
Carol,Carol,450,120
Dan,Dan,400,200
Ellen,Ellen,360,40
```

The first and third columns (EmpReg, RegPay) come from one source and the second and third columns (EmpOT, OTPay) come from a second source. My objective is output that looks like this.

```
Emp,Pay
Alice,420
Bob,300
Carol,570
Dan,600
Ellen,400
```

Here is the code that I have been trying, at least what I have saved.

```scala
var q2 = q.join(q1, q("EmpReg") === q1("EmpOT"), "fullouter")
//q2 = q2.select("EmpReg", ($"RegPay" + $"OTPay"))
//q2 = q2.groupBy($"EmpReg".sum($"RegPay" + $"OTPay"))
var add = q2.select(($"RegPay" + $"OTPay"))                    
//q2 = q2.sum("RegPay", "OTPay")
//q2 = q2.groupBy("EmpReg", "EmpOT")
//var q2 = q.join(q1).where("EmpReg") === "EmpOT"))
//q2 = q2.select("EmpReg").sum("RegPay",  "OTPay")
//q2.show
add.show
```

[q] is the first file which represents regular pay. [q1] is the second file which represents overtime pay. [q2] is the combination shown in the first example above.  Primary keys are [EmpReg] and [EmpOT]. don't really need to combine [EmpReg] and [EmpOT] since they are the same, and it doesn't make any difference which I use.

I really need to add [RegPay] and [OTPay] to get [Pay], but for the life of me I can't get it to work. The lines commented out return various errors. I can add the two pay columns, and select an appropriate employee column, but can't seem to do it in one query. I am constrained to use Scala on Databricks. Othewise, I might do something like this.

```sql
select q.EmpReg as Emp, (q.RegPay + q1.OTPay) as Pay
  from q join q1 on q.EmpReg = q1.EmpOT
```

(Why can't things ever be simple?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a similar approach as in your SQL query:

```
val q2 = q.join(q1, q("EmpReg") === q1("EmpOT"), "fullouter")

val add = q2.select(q("EmpReg").as("Emp"), (q("RegPay") + q1("OTPay")).as("Pay"))
```

---

Your code has this line

```
q2.select("EmpReg", ($"RegPay" + $"OTPay"))
```

which should work if you add `$` before `"EmpReg"`. You can't have both strings and columns in the `select` statement. This works in Python but not Scala.

Comment: Yep, sure did work! What, exactly, does the $ do? (As an old Perl hack, I miss $scalars, @arrays, %hashes, and &subs.)

Comment: `$` is a shorthand notation for `col`, used for selecting columns.

Comment: @ccc31807 if the answer is helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking the tick button, thanks!